# Is FC-center of a topologically finitely generated profinite group closed?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, profinite-groups

Let $ G $ be a group. A element $ g\in G $ is an *FC-element* if it has only finitely many conjugates in $ G $. The set $ \Delta(G) $ of FC-elements of $ G $ is a characteristic subgroup of $ G $, and it is called the *FC-center* of $ G $.

**Question:** Suppose that $G$ is a topologically finitely generated profinite group. Is $ \Delta(G) $ closed in $G$?

Note that it's not true without the condition "topologically finitely generated", see Page 1281 in [Profinite Groups with Restricted Centralizers](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2161199). Since $G$ is topologically finitely generated,   the topology on $G$ should be determined by the algebraic structure, cf. [On finitely generated profinite groups, I: strong completeness and uniform bounds](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2007/165-1/p05). Hence, it seems that the answer should be Yes in our case. Any references would be appreciated.

All I know is the following: Firstly, note that $\Delta(G)$ is just the union of all centralisers $C_G(H)$ of all (abstract) subgroup $H$ of finite index. Here each $H$ must be open since $G$ is topologically finitely generated. Also, one can show that each $C_G(H)$ is closed. For each natural number $n$, it's well known that the number of open subgroups of $G$ of index $n$ is finite. What's the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Consider the group $\prod_{n\ge 5}\mathrm{Alt}(n)$. Then it is topologically 2-generated. Its FC-center is $\bigoplus_{n\ge 5}\mathrm{Alt}(n)$, which is dense but not closed.